# Missing time values in R - memory issues

Tags: r, memory, out-of-memory, time-series, dplyr

I want to add missing observations in my panel data set, but keep running into memory issues.

I use the following code (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36032858/add-missing-values-in-time-series-efficiently) topic):

```
library(dplyr)

group_by(df, group) %>% 
  complete(time = full_seq(time 1L)) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(replace(., which(is.na(.)), 0)), -group, -time)
```

My data would look similar to the data in that topic, thus:

```
group   time           value
1           1          50
1           3          52
1           4          10
2           1          4
2           4          84
2           5          2
```

which I would like to look like

```
group  time        value
1           1       50
1           2       0
1           3       52
1           4       10
2           1       4
2           2       0
2           3       0
2           4       84
2           5       2
```

The problem is that I keep running out of memory (it is a only a 1 GB file with around 1.5 million observations). Any suggestions on how to do this differently?

Comment: You can start by splitting your file in smaller chunks, then apply the completion to all of them, and then merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If memory is an issue, you might try it with the *data.table*-package:

**Option 1:**

```
# convert to a data.table
setDT(df)
# create a reference table
new.df <- df[, .(time = min(time):max(time)), group]
# join and replace the NA-values with zero's
new.df[df, value := i.value, on = names(new.df)][is.na(value), value := 0]
```

which gives:

```
> new.df
   group time value
1:     1    1    50
2:     1    2     0
3:     1    3    52
4:     1    4    10
5:     2    1     4
6:     2    2     0
7:     2    3     0
8:     2    4    84
9:     2    5     2
```

**Option 2:**

```
setDT(df, key='time')[, .SD[J(min(time):max(time))], by = group
                      ][is.na(value), value := 0][]
```

which gives:

```
   group time value
1:     1    1    50
2:     1    2     0
3:     1    3    52
4:     1    4    10
5:     2    1     4
6:     2    2     0
7:     2    3     0
8:     2    4    84
9:     2    5     2
```

Comment: great thanks a lot, second approach worked perfectly and is fast!